# How to change text by the user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that contains `<input>` and `<span>`.

I don't know how to do that the text that the user write in the input, will appear as the span.

the code (that doesn't work well):

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Lets talk with SpongBob!</h1>
<span>Say "hello":</span>
<form name="frm"><input name="question" type="text"><input  id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
<div id="igool"><span id="talk"></span></div>
<div id="Triangle"></div>
<img src="http://static.tumblr.com/f1bbfdf0fd794b1cf8d243d65644be01/i0ldeup/bURmj2ccf/tumblr_static_spongebob.jpg"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
 body {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 20%;
}
input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 45%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
#submit {
    margin-left: 57%;
    width: 5%;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 37%;
  }
#Triangle {
  width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;

    border-top: 30px solid lightgray;
  margin-top: -0.5%;
  margin-left: 41%;

}
#igool {
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border-radius: 100%;
    margin-left: 38%;
  margin-top: 8%;
}
#talk {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-top: 3%;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
if (document.forms['frm'].question.value == "hello") {
    document.getElementById("talk").innerHTML="Hello you to!";
}
else {
    document.getElementById("talk").innerHTML="WhatEver...";
}
```

Comment: when do you want it to work? when you click on submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to actually submit the form, if all you got is JavaScript then have such code instead:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var oForm = document.forms["frm"];
    var oTalkSpan = document.getElementById("talk");
    oForm.onsubmit = function() {
        if (this.elements["question"].value == "hello") {
            oTalkSpan.innerHTML="Hello you to!";
        }
        else {
            oTalkSpan.innerHTML="WhatEver...";
        }
        return false;
    };
};
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/HkD9g/).

If you do choose to submit the form, you'll have to use server side language like PHP, ASP.NET or many others but you can't use client side scripting for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you need JavaScript events. Lookup `blur()` or `keyup()` and that should do it. You would need to wire those to the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/BQ26q/)

```
document.forms['frm'].onsubmit = function() {
    if (document.forms['frm'].question.value == "hello") {
        document.getElementById("talk").innerHTML="Hello you to!";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("talk").innerHTML="WhatEver...";
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in just three lines with jquery like this:

```
$('input#one').keyup(function(){

$('span#test').html($(this).val());

})
```

and html:

```
<span id="test"></span>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="one"/>
```

Here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zDk8w/)